# When installing gems, how to automatically install dependancies?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

```
gem install mygem
ERROR:  Error installing mygem:
        mygem requires mygem-adapter (>= 0, runtime)
```

I was wondering if there was an easy way to automatically install dependent gems when I want to install a gem?  Something like `gem install mygem -with_dependancies`.  Is something like this possible?

Comment: It looks like that your dependent gem is not in a repo.  Gem install looks by default at rubygems.org so if this is an in-house gem you need to specify the path or your own gemserver.  gem by defualt puts in dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gem` is not finding that dependency because it only pulls dependencies from installed gems and rubygems.org. You need to either:

Add your own gem source as your gem is probably not on rubygems.org (the default)

```
gem install your-gem --source http://mygemserver.com
```

Or

```
  gem install /path/to/mygem.gem
```

Answer (score -2):

Have a look at Bundler (http://gembundler.com) - it simplifies working with gems.